# extract date and time from String object android

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, time

I have a String object that contains expired date and time like `strDateTimeBoj="Oct 11 2014  5:30PM";`

I need it to be extracted to separate date and time , because it needs to be checked with current date and time , whether this date is expired or not ...

I know the following code , but didn't achieved the goal

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(string);
```

How to achieve this .....Any help would be great...

Comment: Can you explain what you try to do. For me it is not clear what's he problem. If you whant to know if the date of the string is before or after now use the Calendar object.

Comment: It seems like you need to become more proficient at reading Javadocs. The docs for [`DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) explain what the different symbols mean. Surely you must have thought `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` didn't look right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way

```
 String strDateTimeBoj="Oct 11 2014 5:30PM";
 //first you need to use proper date formatter
 DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mmaa");
 Date date=df.parse(strDateTimeBoj);// converting String to date
 System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Out put:

```
 Oct 11 2014 05:30PM
```

Which date format should I use?

You can find it out by your own by read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Edit

you can use `before()` `after()` method to compare dates.

```
Date today=new Date();

System.out.println(today.after(date));
System.out.println(today.before(date));
```

Out put:

```
false
true
```

Comment: how do I compare it with current date along with time , to know whether it is expired..

Comment: @karthik you can see my edit.

Comment: Does this also considers the time in the date ...that is 5.30 PM which is included in the Date object

Comment: @karthik it is. you can check by writing some code.

Comment: thank you Ruchira Gayan Ranaweera ...you saved my time .... Sorry I can't vote because of my reputition..

Answer (score 1):

If you need two separate objects, 1 for date and another for time, then may be you can give this a try:

```
String strDateTimeBoj="Oct 11 2014  5:30PM";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
Date dateObj = dateFormat.parse(strDateTimeBoj);
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date timeObj = dateFormat.parse(strDateTimeBoj);
```

But according to me, one object should do what you need to achieve.

```
String strDateTimeBoj="Oct 11 2014  5:30PM";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"); 
Date dateObj = dateFormat.parse(strDateTimeBoj);
```

And compare date with current date.

Comment: how do I compare it with current date along with time , to know whether it is expired..

Comment: @karthik refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132106/how-do-i-compare-current-date-with-user-input-date-from-date-picker)

Answer (score 0):

Use following formatter:

```
String string="Oct 11 2014 5:30PM";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mma");
Date dt = formatter.parse(string);
System.out.println(formatter.format(dt));
```

**Output :**

```
Oct 11 2014 05:30PM
```

Comment: DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("Oct 11 2014  5:30PM");
   Log.v("DateTimeFormatter", String.valueOf(dt));

Comment: shows  IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Oct 11 2014  5:30PM"

Answer (score 0):

You could get time in any format by using SimpleDateFormat class. Please refer to this  `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String currentDate = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"/"+(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"/"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                 Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(currentDate);`